# Errors when passing value between pages in GUI using Java.

Tags: java, user-interface, linked-list

I am doing a bookstore inventory system using my own linked list and all the other code functions well. I want to generate some kind of summary in the last function, like showing how many entries is in the list and calculate how many entries are there in every genre. There is no error show in codes and I have debugged the program also nothing shows.

The error is, once I clicked the button, it shows me a summary of how many entries are in the list and how many books are there in fiction and nonfiction. The number of entries and fiction part works well, but the nonfiction keeps giving me 0 even through I have a book which is under nonfiction in genre.

The `reportfiction()` method code and `reportnonfiction()` method code are almost the same so I don't get why one works and the others cannot.

Here is my Report Page code:

```
public class Report extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Report() {
        initComponents();
        jTextArea1.setText("SUMMARY REPORT OF STATE LIBRARY\n\n"+"Total Number of Entries: "+LinkedList.countNodes()+"\n\nTotal Number of Books By Genre: "+"\nFiction: "+LinkedList.reportfiction()+"\nNon-Fiction: "+LinkedList.reportnonfiction());
        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

Here is the method that I called inside the Report Page:

```
public static int reportfiction()
{
    Node current = head;
    int fiction = 0;
    while(current.next != null){
       if("Fiction".equals(current.data.getGenre)){
           fiction++;
           current = current.next;
       }
   }
    return fiction;
}

public static int reportnonfiction()
{
    Node current = head;
    int nonfiction = 0;
    while(current.next != null){
       if("NonFiction".equals(current.data.getGenre)){
           nonfiction++;
           current = current.next;
       }
   }
    return nonfiction;
}
```

Here is my Data class (Use to store all the book information):

```
public class Data {
LinkedList list;
String name;
String author;
int isbn;
int number;
String genre;

public Data(String name, String author, int isbn, int number, String genre)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.number = number;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String toString()
{
    return("Book Name: "+name+"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nISBN Number: "+isbn+"\nNumber of Copies: "+number+"\nGenre: "+genre+"\n\n");
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getGenre()
{
    return genre;
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me the nonfiction part cannot work? When I display, for example I have 1 book in Fiction, 1 book in Non-Fiction, after I click the button, it will only shows me Fiction: 1 and Non-Fiction: 0.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes I did, debugged and shows nothing error as well.